# How can I store local variables into class variables in java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a interactive application in Java and one of my local variables isn't adding itself into the class variable which is screwing up my final output.

Here is the class variable `public static double deduction;`

Here is what I'm trying to store into it

```
System.out.println("Do you want medical insurance?");
String choice = kb.nextLine();       
if (choice == "yes")
{
    medIns =  32.50;
}
else
{
    medIns = 0;
}
System.out.println("Do you want dental insurance?");
choice = kb.nextLine();
if (choice == "yes")
{
    dentIns = 20.00;
}
else
{
    dentIns = 0;
}
System.out.println("Do you want long-term disability insurance?");
choice = kb.nextLine();
if (choice == "yes")
{
    lifeIns = 10.00;
}
else
{
    lifeIns = 0;
}
deduction = medIns + dentIns + lifeIns;
return deduction;`
```

Here is what it's finally going into `totalpay = gross + (gross * retire) - deduction;`

When I put in all the other input it's not storing the local deduction into the class deduction so it can be processed into my totalpay calculation.

Comment: Are you also declaring a local variable called `deduction` in that method?

Comment: Post complete code please. In this case it's important.

Answer (score 3):

#### Your if/else statements are always false!

`deduction = medIns + dentIns + lifeIns;` is always `deduction = 0 + 0 + 0;` no matter what the inputs are given your mis-use of the `==` operator.

#### == vs .equals() vs .equalsIgnoreCase()

`choice == "yes"` is not how you compare `Strings` in Java, in your case this will never be `true`.

`==` compares *identity* ( is the left hand side the exact same object instance as the right hand side ), `.equals()` and `.equalsIgnoreCase()` is how you compare contents of `String` objects in Java.

#### Idiomatic Solution

In your case the correct approach is `"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(choice.trim())` putting the literal first avoids having to check for `null`.

a more comprehensive solution would to match on a regular expression

`choice.matches("(?i)^y.*")` which would match anything that starts with a `y` and has zero or more characters regardless of case, given that `choice` isn't `null`.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question though...

Comment: yes it does, the code isn't ever going to add anything but `0` in both those `if/else` blocks.

Comment: YOu should add that explanation then. The way your answer reads now, makes it sound like an unrelated comment. I really only realized that you are right now, that I read your comment.

Comment: Ok Jarrod I replaced choice == "yes" with "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(choice.trim()) and it's still coming up 0??

Comment: there isn't enough code provided to help you anymore ... we need an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).